# How to check a domain age using php

Tags: php, networking, dns

Hello I was wondering if there is a nice way to find out what is the age of a specific domain.

But I want to find out a way to do this programmatically asking the DNS to check a domain age using php and not from an online tool.

I am searching on the internet to find out how google is checking my domain age and other SEO tools.

Is this information private for a domain where you must have special permissions to ask what a domains age is? And if yes? How come google knows my domain age? noone asked my domains age.. how come they know it?

Comment: see this article http://99webtools.com/domain-age-checker-script.php

Comment: i would say why not using php to connect to an API:
https://api.domaintools.com/v1/domaintools.com/whois/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois), most recently defined in [RFC3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912):

```
$ whois stackoverflow.com

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM
   Registrar: GODADDY.COM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
   Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com
   Name Server: NS1.SERVERFAULT.COM
   Name Server: NS2.SERVERFAULT.COM
   Name Server: NS3.SERVERFAULT.COM
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientRenewProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited
   Updated Date: 30-nov-2010
   Creation Date: 26-dec-2003
   Expiration Date: 26-dec-2014
   
   [...]
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [Whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) service.

[PHPWhois](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/): PHP class for whois queries, can query the correct whois server for domain names, ip addresses and AS handles and returns data in a structured array.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a php script or a web service?

If a web service, then check out this [bulk domain age checker](http://www.bulkseotools.com/bulk-check-domain-age.php) tool, it let you find out domain registration date and expiration date plus registrar name. You can bulk check 500 domains at once.

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Registration date is available via WHOIS for most TLDs, and is not in DNS.

For com/net domains, you can check whois.internic.net for the "Creation Date".  For most country TLDs, you can find WHOIS servers by doing a DNS query of "*country-code*.whois-servers.net".  The command line WHOIS client in most BSD and Linux variants will look for the proper WHOIS servers automatically.

Note that each registrar has their own format for presenting this information, and most have implemented controls on their WHOIS servers to restrict frequent requests from the same IP address.

Have a look at [PHPWhois](http://www.phpwhois.org/).

Comment: when i do a whois command, who am i asking? the dns? or another service?

Comment: You're asking a WHOIS server.  WHOIS is its own protocol that runs on TCP port 43, just as HTTP runs on tcp port 80, DNS runs on udp port 53.  The WHOIS program at your command line is a client for that protocol, just as Firefox is an HTTP client.  Your client makes a connection to a server, issues a request, then interprets and/or displays the results for you.

Comment: There are some rules about where to find the appropriate whois server for a particlar top-level domain that most whois clients already know about.  Have a look at the [whois man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=whois) for more information.  Also, for an excellent web-based whois option, check out [Uwhois.com](http://www.uwhois.com/cgi/domains.cgi?User=NoAds).

Answer (score 1):

Use this PHP script to check domain age and here you can find working [domain age checker](http://seotablets.com/domain-age-checker)

```
class DomainAge{

  private $WHOIS_SERVERS=array(

  "com"=>array("whois.verisign-grs.com","/Creation Date:(.*)/"),

  "net"=>array("whois.verisign-grs.com","/Creation Date:(.*)/"),

  "org"=>array("whois.pir.org","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "info"=>array("whois.afilias.info","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "biz"=>array("whois.neulevel.biz","/Domain Registration Date:(.*)/"),

  "us"=>array("whois.nic.us","/Domain Registration Date:(.*)/"),

  "uk"=>array("whois.nic.uk","/Registered on:(.*)/"),

  "ca"=>array("whois.cira.ca","/Creation date:(.*)/"),

  "tel"=>array("whois.nic.tel","/Domain Registration Date:(.*)/"),

  "ie"=>array("whois.iedr.ie","/registration:(.*)/"),

  "it"=>array("whois.nic.it","/Created:(.*)/"),

  "cc"=>array("whois.nic.cc","/Creation Date:(.*)/"),

  "ws"=>array("whois.nic.ws","/Domain Created:(.*)/"),

  "sc"=>array("whois2.afilias-grs.net","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "mobi"=>array("whois.dotmobiregistry.net","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "pro"=>array("whois.registrypro.pro","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "edu"=>array("whois.educause.net","/Domain record activated:(.*)/"),

  "tv"=>array("whois.nic.tv","/Creation Date:(.*)/"),

  "travel"=>array("whois.nic.travel","/Domain Registration Date:(.*)/"),

  "in"=>array("whois.inregistry.net","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "me"=>array("whois.nic.me","/Domain Create Date:(.*)/"),

  "cn"=>array("whois.cnnic.cn","/Registration Date:(.*)/"),

  "asia"=>array("whois.nic.asia","/Domain Create Date:(.*)/"),

  "ro"=>array("whois.rotld.ro","/Registered On:(.*)/"),

  "aero"=> array("whois.aero","/Created On:(.*)/"),

  "nu"=> array("whois.nic.nu","/created:(.*)/")
  );

  public function age($domain)
  {

  $domain = trim($domain);

  if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") 

  $domain = substr($domain, 7); // remove http:// if included

  if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") 

   $domain = substr($domain, 4);//remove www from domain

  if(preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9]{2,100}).([a-z.]{2,8})$/i",$domain))
  {

  $domain_parts = explode(".", $domain);

  $tld = strtolower(array_pop($domain_parts));

  if(!$server=$this->WHOIS_SERVERS[$tld][0]) {

  return false;

  }

  $res=$this->queryWhois($server,$domain);

  if(preg_match($this->WHOIS_SERVERS[$tld][1],$res,$match))

  {

  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

  $time = time() - strtotime($match[1]);

  $years = floor($time / 31556926);

  $days = floor(($time % 31556926) / 86400);

  if($years == "1") {$y= "1 year";

}
  else 

{
$y = $years . " years";
}
  if($days == "1") {$d = "1 day";
}
  else 
{
$d = $days . " days";
}
  return "$y, $d";

 }
  else

  return false;
}
  else

  return false;

}

  private function queryWhois($server,$domain)

  {

  $fp = @fsockopen($server, 43, $errno, $errstr, 20) or die("Socket Error " 
  . $errno . " - " . $errstr);

if($server=="whois.verisign-grs.com")

$domain="=".$domain;

  fputs($fp, $domain . "rn");
  $out = "";

  while(!feof($fp)){

  $out .= fgets($fp);

  }
  fclose($fp);

  return $out;
  }

}
```

Comment: That class didn't work for me until I added back slashes before "r" and "n" in the fputs command near the end. `fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");` Then it worked great!

Comment: @AamishSohail, Can you re-check this **URL** http://seotablets.com/domain-age-checker Please

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the Registration Data Access Protocol, **RDAP** seems to have replaced the old WHOIS for good.  Its main advantage is a unique format worldwide, detailed in a series of RFCs.  Since 2021 it is an **Internet Standard**.  It is operated via http(s).  There are several *bootstrap* servers one may query, including [rdap.org](https://about.rdap.org/), [iana.org](https://www.iana.org/assignments/rdap-dns/rdap-dns.xhtml), [arin.net](https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/rdap/).  They'll most likely hand out an http `302 redirect` to the actual provider.

Eventually, one will reply with a JSON formatted record which includes an array of *events*, for example:

```
  "events": [
    {
      "eventAction": "expiration",
      "eventDate": "2024-05-24T13:04:21.595Z"
    },
    {
      "eventAction": "registration",
      "eventDate": "2023-05-24T13:04:21.595Z"
    },
    {
      "eventAction": "last changed",
      "eventDate": "2023-05-24T13:04:24.454Z"
    },
    {
      "eventAction": "last update of RDAP database",
      "eventDate": "2023-05-25T07:33:59.494Z"
    }
  ],
```

([RFC 9083](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9083) specifies 9 types of action, and `last update of RDAP database` is not among them.  It appeared in an [expired draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-lozano-rdap-gtld-whois-additional-events-00) and was not standardized as it is [not an action against the object](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/weirds/z9QEpW97ZMsn4vT91F40q_oBm50/)).

It is plenty of libraries for either downloading a file via http or parsing JSON.  This approach is way more general than trying to enumerate each provider's format idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 0):

Short function to get domain age using the information about rdap.org from Ale:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://example.com/";
    echo "Domain Create Date of $url " . date( 'F Y', strtotime( domainCreate($url) ) ) . " (" . domainCreate($url) . ")";
    
    function domainCreate($url){
        $parsed = parse_url( $url );
        $domain = trim( $parsed[ 'host' ] );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://rdap.org/domain/$domain" );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        $data = curl_exec( $ch );
        $data = json_decode( $data, true );
        curl_close( $ch );

        return( $data[ 'events' ][ 0 ][ 'eventDate' ] );
    }
?>
```

Outputs something like this:

> Domain Create Date of https://example.com/ August 1995 (1995-08-14T04:00:00Z)